# How to assign a font for IElement with itextsharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext, export-to-pdf

I've created one pdf document using `itextsharp` and would like to populate it with data from a html document

```
string htmlText = htmlcode.ToString();

var styles = new StyleSheet();
styles.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.TABLE, "border", "2");

var htmlarraylist = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader(htmlText), styles);
document.Open();
```

//here I create font for text

```
BaseFont baseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1250,
                                                             BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
Font font = new Font(baseFont, 8);
```

//Now I add element to pdf

```
foreach (IElement t in htmlarraylist)
{
    document.Add((IElement)t);                        
}
```

//How can I add font for every element from htmlarraylist?

//for paragraph is like this

```
doc.Add(new Paragraph("țșăî", font));
```

but how set this font for IElement?

```
document.Close();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Itextsharp set font for IElement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562589/itextsharp-set-font-for-ielement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IElement have a Font property you can assign you font to it

Example:

```
foreach (IElement t in htmlarraylist)
{
        t.Font = font;
        document.Add(t);
}
```

Comment: I want to add BaseFont.CP1250 for diacritics style.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.TABLE, HtmlTags.FACE, "times-roman"); not work right

Comment: @Alex I have corrected the line t.Font = font; in the foreach loop

Comment: @Alex looks like the IElement does not have property called Font, so please cast t to Element like this ((Element)t).Font = font; hope this helps. Mind you their will be elemenst that dont have Font property in them so you will have to filter out those

Comment: still doesn't work, ((Element)t).Font Cannot resolve symbol 'Font' ((

Comment: @Alex the only suggestion I can give is put a break point inside the foreach and find out what are the properties for ((Element)t it might as simple as the "font" instead of "Font"