# iTextSharp set default font-size

Tags: c#, itext

I am using iTextSharp to create a new pdf-file.
The pdf will contain one headline and one pdf-table.
The file-size of the resultant pdf-file should be as small as possible, so I use the default font (Helvetica, 12pt). 
Is there a way to change the default-font-size from 12pt to 8pt.

I know that I can set the font for each pdf-table-cell.

But is it possible to set the default-font-size for the whole document/table, so that I don't need to set the font for each and every table-cell extra?

(I googled on this topic, but did not find an answer)

Comment: try this link --------------> https://stackoverflow.com/a/11577770/5323912

Comment: Setting a default font size for *all* objects is only possible in iText 7. If you are using an old version, you have to set a `Font` with the desired size for every separate object. Is there a reason why you chose to use an old version of iText?

Comment: Changing the font size will not make the file-size go down.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);

iTextSharp.text.Font font = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bf, 10, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL);


Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph(new Chunk("Sample text", font));
```

Comment: I think the best thing for the OP to do is wrap your code in a method and simply call that everywhere. Or switch to iText7.