# How to set font size in C# using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I tried this method to set the font size, which was answered here: [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11577465/set-font-for-all-text-from-pdfptable-with-itextsharp/66982921?noredirect=1#comment118401052_66982921)

Before is my code which does **not** change the font size.

```
var bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
var myFont = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bf, 18, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL);
    
foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in phrasesDataGridView.Columns)
{
    if (columnsToPrint.Contains(column.HeaderText))
    {
        var cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(column.HeaderText))
        {
            Phrase = {Font = myFont}
        };
        pdfTable.AddCell(cell);
    }
}
```

What should I change to make this work?

Thanks

Comment: Which version of ITextSharp are you using? And have you looked at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45833882/itextsharp-set-default-font-size

Comment: I use iSharpText 5.5.13.1 (newest is 5.5.13.2)