# Can't find text in PdfTable

Tags: c#, itext, pdfptable

```
BaseFont Vn_Helvetica = BaseFont.CreateFont(@"C:\Windows\Fonts\arial.ttf", 
"Identity-H", BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
Font fontNormal = new Font(Vn_Helvetica, 12, Font.NORMAL);
foreach (var t in htmlarraylist)
                {

 if (t is PdfPTable)
                    {
                        var countColumn= ((PdfPTable)t).NumberOfColumns;//is 7
                        var countRows = ((PdfPTable)t).Rows;//is 10
```

//I want set normalFont for all the text  but defaultCell.Phrase is always null

```
((PdfPTable)t).DefaultCell.Phrase = new Phrase() { Font = fontNormal };
```

//how to find text in pdfptable to set the font?

```
                    }
                   document.Add(t);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Itextsharp set font for IElement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562589/itextsharp-set-font-for-ielement)

Comment: Not quite a duplicate, similar but different!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to set the font on the phrase for the default cell of the table. You need to set this for all cells on the table:

```
        // t is a PdfPTable
        foreach(var row in t.Rows)
        {
            foreach(var cell in row.GetCells())
            {
                if(cell.Phrase != null)
                {
                    cell.Phrase.Font = fontNormal;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you have an example PDF I could test with?

Comment: I solved my problem by another method which didn't require a search for text in pdfptable
thanks for the help